# Need help with java programming!

Tags: java, ubuntu-10.04

i am new to java and i just made my first program: HelloWorld and after i compiled it I tried to run it and it gave me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266) Could not find
>   the main class: HelloWorld. Program will exit.

I am using ubuntu version 10.04, I made the program with geany, and compiled it in terminal by using the command `javac HelloWorld.java`.
Then i ran it in terminal with the command: `java HelloWorld` and then had the error above.
my `HelloWorld.java` file looks like this:

```
public class  HelloWorld {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
             System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

then my `HelloWorld.class` file looks like this:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
```

Comment: `java -classpath . HelloWorld` should work if HelloWorld.class is in your current working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to run your java command directly from the directory that contains your .class file, or you need define the classpath, that is, the place where the JVM can find your compiled  Java class. Try:

```
java -classpath <directory> HelloWorld
```

where `<directory>` is the (relative) path to the directory containing your HelloWorld.class file.

Comment: i tried typing: java -classpath '/home/(user)/Desktop/java1' HelloWorld       but i gave me this error:    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 1886741100 in class file HelloWorld
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)

Answer (score 1):

Check what JVM is installed on your system. I had same issue with OpenJDK. After removing it and installing Oracle JDK the issue has gone. You can also specify correct JDK path in Project > Properties > Build > Execute Commands. I.g., $JAVA_HOME/bin/java "%e" for Execute command.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your program, looks like you may be typing:

```
java HelloWorld.class
```

instead of

```
java HelloWorld
```

When I tried it, it worked like it was supposed to, except when I included ".class", which caused it to give the error you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to Jeen Broekstra's solution I would suggest looking through your code for "slanty" quotations - [See here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/517155/java/java/Incompatible-magic-value).

Then try compiling: `javac HelloWorld.class`
and running: `java -classpath '/home/(user)/Desktop/java1' HelloWorld`
again.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem in Geany. I realised I was clicking on the "Build" option (on my toolbar it looks like a brick) instead of "Compile" (blue polyhedron converted to red sphere).